# Numerical solution of the advection equation with Crank–Nicolson finite difference method

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, time-integration, advection-diffusion, advection

I need to implement a numerical scheme for the solution of the one-dimensional advection equation
$$\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + C(x, t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0 \\\\$$
$$ \\ C(x,t) = \frac{\pi\cos(2 \pi t) + 3.5}{2\pi - \pi\sin(\pi x)} \\\\$$
$$\\ 0 \leq x \leq 1, \quad 0 \leq t \leq 1\\\\$$

with Crank–Nicolson finite difference method
$$\\ \frac{u^{j + 1}_{k} - u^{j}_{k}}{\tau} + \frac{C}{4h}(u^{j + 1}_{k + 1} - u^{j + 1}_{k - 1} + u^{j}_{k + 1} - u^{j}_{k - 1}) = 0\\\\$$
and boundary conditions
$$\\ \phi(x) = u(x,0), \quad \psi_{0}(t) = u(0,t), \quad \psi_{1}(t) = u(1, t) \\\\$$

it's known that the exact solution has the following form
$$\\ U(x,t) = \cos(\pi x) - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2 \pi t) + 2\pi x - 3.5t\\\\$$

The numerical solution on each layer in time is found as the solution of a system of linear equations with a tridiagonal matrix
$$\\ Au = b \\\\$$
$$\\ A =  
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac{C\tau}{4h} & 0 & ...\\
-\frac{C\tau}{4h} & 1 & \frac{C\tau}{4h} & ... \\
0 & -\frac{C\tau}{4h} & 1 & ... \\
... & ... & ... & ...
\end{pmatrix}\\\\$$

I've write a simple python [script](https://gist.github.com/Winabryr/1d6d7aee1407e781ab3864ae5b1ef483), but the result doesn't match the theory:

> [image: graph]

I'm sure I'm wrong somewhere, but I don't see where.
Thanks!

Comment: Speed $C$ is positive at $x=1$. You cannot specify dirichlet conditions at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks about the code, perhaps cleaning these up already solves the question, especially the initialization error:

Floating point errors are a thing, so if you want to get the expected results, give some wiggle room (`0.01` is arbitrary, I would not expect defects above `1e-12` in this place)

```
  N = int((x1 - x0) / h + 0.01)
  M = int((t1 - t0) / tau + 0.01)
```

There is no guarantee that $N·h=x_1-x_0$ etc., so force this grid condition

```
h = (x1 - x0) / N
tau = (t1 - t0) / M
```

There is a honest error in the side boundary initialization, the space component is always first

```
    u[0, i] = psi_0(i * tau)
    u[N, i] = psi_1(i * tau)
```

The implicit trapezoidal method that is the method in time direction of C-N reads as
$$
\frac{y^{j+1}-y^j}{\tau}=\frac{F(t^j,y^j)+F(t^{j+1},y^{j+1})}2.
$$
Accordingly, the coefficients `a_h` for the banded matrix should be computed at time `(j+1)*tau` to get the correct order $O(\tau^2+h^2)$ of the method.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, I am little ashamed of such obvious errors. Unfortunately, fixing these doesn't solve the question, perhaps there are more issues.